# How do you call variables put into a text file from a batch into a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I was Creating a quiz as a test of my skills and was able to successfully put text and a variables into a separate text file. When I tried to call them from the batch file, the variables were blank. How can I fix this? Also, if anyone can tell me how to recall a specific line, I would be grateful.

My Code (Shortened):

```
Echo What is your Name?
set /p Name=Name=
echo Test Results: > TestResults.txt
echo Name: %Name% >> TestResults.txt
cls
echo What's 2 + 2?
set /p Problem=2 + 2= 
echo 2 + 2= %Problem% >> TestResults.txt
cls
echo Who is President?
set /p President=President= 
echo President= %President% >> TestResults.txt
cls
echo Goodbye!
pause>nul
cls
for /f "delims= " %%G in (TestResults.txt) do echo %%G
pause>nul
```

Comment: Can you please verify that the code you've provided doesn't work? The only problem I'm having with it is that the space in the delims section of the for loop means that it can't handle answers with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at your output, it should give you a clue to the problem.

When you TYPE the resultant file, it should have all the expected data:

```
c:\>TYPE TestResults.txt
Test Results:
Name: Simple Simon
2 + 2= 16
President= Bugs Bunny
```

But your FOR /F loop is producing:

```
Test
Name:
2
President=
```

Nothing appears after the fist space in each line. Look at your DELIMS option and it should be obvious you are setting the token delimiter to be a `<space>`. Simply make sure the DELIMS option is the last option in the list, and put the closing quote immediately after DELIMS=, and prolem is solved.

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in (TestResults.txt) do echo %%G
```